# Thinkpad X220 power manager ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, power

I'm running xubuntu on a thinkpad x220, with a 9 cell battery and i'm only getting 7 hours with chromium running, browsing the web. Powertop says that i'm using around 11 Watts at this state. Are there any ways to reduce battery consumption, like the power manager for windows/

Thanks

Comment: "only" 7 hours? Have you tried it in windows, what do you get there? Do you have switchable graphics? Which cpu governor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I disable a number of things on my x220 using (you have to run this on every reboot)

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down # no ethernet
echo disable | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/bluetooth # no bluetooth
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/i915/parameters/i915_enable_rc6
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/i915/parameters/i915_enable_fbc
```

although to be honest, I never bothered checking if any of the above ever made a real difference.